# Windows hidden godoc

Tags: windows, batch-file, godoc

I am having problems starting a godoc server hidden on my windows development machine.
The idea is to have a batch that starts godoc and opens it in my browser.
So far that works, but I cannot get rid of a console window holding the godoc output log.
Is there some way to start it completely in the background?

My batch:

```
#start cmd /c "godoc -http=:8080 -goroot=D:\Programmieren\Go\pkg > nul"
#start godoc -http=:8080 -goroot=D:\Programmieren\Go\pkg > nul
#Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
#oShell.Run "godoc -http=:8080 -goroot=D:\Programmieren\Go\pkg", 0, true
start godoc -http=:8080 -goroot=D:\Programmieren\Go\pkg
start "" http://localhost:8080/pkg/
```

The commented lines are things I have tried without success so far.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to do it with Vbscript which is what you need to do. You can't hide the console with any batch file commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to run a cmd with the commands you must create a vbs file to call the file as a hidden console. So create a file called something like `hidden.vbs` and add:

```
Set MyScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "C:\path to batch\yourbatch.cmd", 0, False
```

Where `C:\path to batch\yourbatch.cmd` is the path to your batch file.

Your batch file can then be as such:

```
start "" godoc -http=:8080 -goroot=D:\Programmieren\Go\pkg && start "" http://localhost:8080/pkg/
```

Then run the `vbs` file which will silently call the batch file.

Comment: It works. When the code regarding WScript.Shell is run from a .vbs file instead of a batch file, it wont permanently open the command window. Actually you can just ditch the batch altogether and put all code into the vbScript that way.

Comment: @user2089648 Yes, hence why I said if you really want to use batch as well :)